# How to search & output a data in python?

Tags: python

First of all, I'm a newbie to Python. I'm just practicing.

I have made users to input a certain data into the memory by using append.

```
store = []
def inputData():
    name = input("Name: ")
    amount = input("Amount: ")
    date = input("Data: ")
    store.append({'name':name, 'amount':amount, 'date':date})
```

I want to let users be able to search the data stored in the memory.

Any hints would be really appreciated.

======================================

Here is my output code

```
def outputData():
      print("="*30)
      print("Name / Amount / Date")
      print("="*30)
      for d in store:
            print("%(name)s %(amount)s %(date)s"%d)
```

Comment: Could you give an example of what the output should be like? I think you might be able to use a dictionary for this.

Comment: I added onto my original posting

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What are you searching for?

Answer (score 0):

```
def outputData(data):
    print("="*30)
    print("Name / Amount / Date")
    print("="*30)
    for person in data:
        print("{name} {amount} {date}".format(**person))
```

Where 'data' is the dictionary where you store the values.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've been trying to understand what it means.Is there any way to just output the data that the user has searched? Here is what I think : 1) user inputs a data to a variable 2) check if the input data is in the dictionary (data[]) 3) if it is in the dictionary, it outputs the value

Comment: You can use an if statement like "if variable in data" and if it is , print it, else: add it to the dictionary. Also, if the answer was what you were looking for feel free to accept the answer. If you have any more questions feel free to ask them :D